# How can I display unique words contained in a Bash string?

Tags: text-processing, awk

The contents of the words file:

```
a-b-c
c-b-a
c-a-b
d-a-x‬
```

I would like the output only:

```
a-b-c
d-a-x
```

because the following:

```
c-b-a  
c-a-b
```

have those combinations from `a-b-c`

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to U&L.  What have you tried?  How did it not work as expected or intended?

Comment: Sorry, output should be:

c-b-a
d-a-x

those 3 words like:

a-b-c
c-b-a
c-a-b

use from the main source "a/b/c"

the output should be:

a-b-c
d-a-x

because c-b-a & c-a-b have those combinations from a-b-c

Comment: a-b-c because it c-a-b and c-b-a have those combinations already.. d-a-x because it doesn't have those a-b-c combination

Comment: So you need to split each string on `-`, and create an associative array key from the *sorted* elements - then you can employ a standard `!seen[key]` test

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me

Comment: Can you specify what the input looks like?  Will every line be (letter) (dash) (letter) (dash) (letter)?  Can there be more or fewer letters (in total)?  Can there be more (or fewer) letters in a cluster?  Are “po-s-t” and “s-t-op” duplicates?  Can there be characters other than letters (e.g., ‘‘t-4-2’’ or ‘‘S-&-H’’)?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I think it could use a couple extra words somewhere, like "cba" and "cab" were excluded because they repeat a previously-seen set "abc", while "dax" was included because it contains characters from an unseen set. Or something along those lines -- just so that there's no guessing involved.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I agree that the question is imprecise and poorly articulated. I don’t see how it’s *missing* what you say it’s missing — it says “I would like the output [to be] only a-b-c [and] d-a-x [and not c-b-a and c-a-b] because … c-b-a [and] c-a-b have those combinations from a-b-c”, which seems to be what you’re asking for. I agree with roaima — my esoteric envelope-pushing aside, it seems fairly straightforward, with no need for guessing.

Comment: Why is "a-b-c" output? It also "has a combination from "a-b-c". I'm wondering if it's *new combinations* that should be output, or only new combinations of "a-b-c" in particular. If there's a "b-c-d" in the input, should it be output?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a perl solution - implementing in awk is left as an exercise:

```
$ perl -F'-' -lnE 'say $_ unless $seen{join "-", sort @F}++' file
a-b-c
d-a-x‬
```

Re-inserting the `-` separator is not necessary in the case that the elements are all single characters, but becomes important otherwise (in order to distinguish `ab-c` from `a-bc` for example).

Comment: +1 for elegance. My preference would have been to write this in perl, too.

Comment: @roaima thanks yeah it's do-able in awk - especially GNU awk >= 4.0 where the array traversal order is controllable via `PROCINFO` - but still neater IMHO in perl

Comment: Even old gawk had `asort()` and some 3.x had envvar `WHINY_USERS` :-{ But (AFAIK) you must still write out the join, as long as you can't/don't use $0/$1..NF

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yeah I realized after I posted that comment that `asort` is actually simpler. I'm still reluctant to add the awk version since the OP appeared to show low effort.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your words really are simple strings separated by dashes, you can use a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) like this

```
#!/bin/bash
# Assumes words are in /tmp/words

while IFS= read line
do
    sorted=$(printf "%s\n" "$line" | tr - '\n' | LC_ALL=C sort | tr '\n' -)
    # printf "sorted= >%s<, line= >%s<\n" "$sorted" "$line" >&2
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$line" "$sorted"
done < /tmp/words |
    sort -t $'\t' -uk2,3 |
    cut -f1
```

The "words" between dashes are separated out, sorted alphanumerically, and rejoined. (Uncomment the `printf` in the middle to see these sorted lines.) This is used as the sort key to `sort` with the uniqueness constraint, so lines containing a duplicate key are discarded. A side-effect is that the original order is changed; if this is unacceptable you should state that as a new requirement in your question. The sorting key is then discarded and the original data output.

Sample output for the data presented in your question

```
a-b-c
d-a-x‬
```

Caveats

1. The data is assumed to be "words" separated by dashes
2. The data is assumed to contain no strange characters (tabs, newlines)

Comment: +1 for this well elaborated and quick answer, although it does not allow dashes to be "escaped", e.g., within "..." or \. Also, if you simply omitted " < /tmp/words " in the script then it could take input from any source file or stream.